# Chrome extension to work on all the sites and perform different action just for few sites

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to make an extension to work on all the site.And also for some site specific sites(Google and LinkedIn) I want some others action to be performed. I have managed to work it on Google search `google.com/search` and LinkedIn search pages `linkedin.com/vsearch/` and perform action A and B respectively. But i'm stuggling to make it work on all others sites to perform action C.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "extname",
  "description": "Welcome to my ext",
   "icons": {
      "48": "images/ext.png"
   },
  "version": "2.6",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "js/background.js","js/select2.min.js","js/lodash.js","js/bootstrap.min.js","js/bootstrap-select.min.js" ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "css": [ "css/select2.css" ,"css/bootstrap.min.css","css/bootstrap-select.min.css"  ],
    "js": [ "js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "js/extension_google_result.js" ,"js/select2.min.js" ,"js/bootstrap.min.js","js/bootstrap-select.min.js"],
    "matches": [ "*://*.google.com/search*" ] //for Google Search page
  },
   {
      "css": [ "css/extension_linkedin_search_page.css", "css/bootstrap.min.css","css/bootstrap-select.min.css" ],
      "js": [ "js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js","js/select2.min.js" ,"js/bootstrap.min.js","js/bootstrap-select.min.js"],
      "matches": [ "*://*.linkedin.com/vsearch/*"] //for Linkedin Search page
   },
  {
      "css": [ "css/extension_linkedin_search_page.css" ,"css/bootstrap.min.css","css/bootstrap-select.min.css","css/select2.css" ],
      "js": ["js/lodash.js", "js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "js/extension_linkedin_sales_navigator_search_page.js" ,"js/select2.min.js" ,"js/bootstrap.min.js","js/bootstrap-select.min.js", "js/akash.js"],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>"] //for all other sites
  }
    ],
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://d37gvrvc0wt4s1.cloudfront.net https://*.pusher.com; object-src 'self'",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/found128.png",
    "default_popup": "html/extension-login-popup.html",
    "default_title": "Search with Found"
  },
  "permissions": ["cookies","tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*","contextMenus", "tabs", "storage", "\u003Call_urls>", "notifications", "webRequest" ]
}
```

But here the first two cases for google and linked in search works perfectly and i'm getting callbacks(Action A and B) on only those pages as expected.I'm also able to call action c on other sites.But actin c is also been calling on google and linkedIn search pages also on every new tab action which i don't want.How can i fix that? Any idea?

Comment: you can't omit certain urls from the manifest.  <all_urls> will work on all urls, regardless of what other matches you have.  You can however contain your code in an if statement that doesn't execute if you are on a linkedin or google search page.

Comment: How can i write if statement in manifest.json?

Comment: I meant in the content script.  like I said, I don't think you can't omit pages in the manifest.  instead, in your script have a if(document.domain!="domainNameIDontLike.com"){runMyCode()}

Comment: @MarcGuiselin And, you've been proven wrong it seems.

Comment: @Xan Interesting.  I've never seen that used in the extensions i've looked at.  Anyway, I wasn't entirely sure of myself, so i wrote a comment instead of an answer, which turned out to be a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), you will find you can use `exclude_matches` in your `manifest.json` to exclude pages that your content script would not be injected into.